# Foreach empty from json

Tags: php, json, foreach

I have the following url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/123456/likes?access_token=__ACCESS_TOKEN__&format=json
```

which I then do:

```
$likesList = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/123456/likes?access_token=$access_token&format=json"),true);
```

which produces e.g.

```
{
"data": [

  {
     "name": "yo yo yo",
     "category": "Entertainer",
     "id": "45640987076",
     "created_time": "2012-04-18T16:14:09+0000"
  },
  {
     "name": "Tony Smith",
     "category": "Musician/band",
     "id": "456456456456",
     "created_time": "2012-02-22T06:56:18+0000"
  },
  {
     "name": "Stations",
     "category": "Company",
     "id": "567657567",
     "created_time": "2012-01-30T23:08:39+0000"
  }

]

}
```

and I then want to list e.g. all the names returned so:

```
foreach ($likesList->data as $element2){ 

    $name = $element2[name];

    echo $name; 

}
```

But it's empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($likesList['data'] as $element2){ 

     $name = $element2['name'];

     echo $name; 
}
```

After json_decode with parameter true you will have associative array. You can access to value by string key. Like in example above.

Comment: Oh, how have I missed that. Correct.

Answer (score 3):

See [this visualization](http://array.include-once.org/?foreach=1&assoc=1&json=%7B%0D%0A%22data%22%3A+%5B%0D%0A%0D%0A++%7B%0D%0A+++++%22name%22%3A+%22yo+yo+yo%22%2C%0D%0A+++++%22category%22%3A+%22Entertainer%22%2C%0D%0A+++++%22id%22%3A+%2245640987076%22%2C%0D%0A+++++%22created_time%22%3A+%222012-04-18T16%3A14%3A09%2B0000%22%0D%0A++%7D%2C%0D%0A++%7B%0D%0A+++++%22name%22%3A+%22Tony+Smith%22%2C%0D%0A+++++%22category%22%3A+%22Musician%2Fband%22%2C%0D%0A+++++%22id%22%3A+%22456456456456%22%2C%0D%0A+++++%22created_time%22%3A+%222012-02-22T06%3A56%3A18%2B0000%22%0D%0A++%7D%2C%0D%0A++%7B%0D%0A+++++%22name%22%3A+%22Stations%22%2C%0D%0A+++++%22category%22%3A+%22Company%22%2C%0D%0A+++++%22id%22%3A+%22567657567%22%2C%0D%0A+++++%22created_time%22%3A+%222012-01-30T23%3A08%3A39%2B0000%22%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D) of your data structure.

As you are receiving an array, you need `$list["data"]` and not `$list->data`. Also don't forget to quote the array key `"name"`.

Comment: I'm impressed. Who did that `include-once` thing?

Comment: That was me. On rare occasions it's useful for these questions.

Comment: Great job.- (StackOverflow is a terrific example of the immense creativity of people doing what they really love) :-)